# Predictions on a two layer trained neural model on Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction

I'm having trouble making predictions with a trained neural model on Tensor. Here's my attempt:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas, numpy as np
dataset=[[0.4,0.5,0.6,0],[0.6,0.7,0.8,1],[0.3,0.8,0.5,2],....]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

Y1 = tf.matmul(X, W) + b

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10, 1]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
Y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Y1, W1) + b1)

# placeholder for correct labels
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# loss function


cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(Y_ * tf.log(Y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.003)
train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    # load batch of images and correct answers
    batch_X, batch_Y = [x[:3] for x in dataset[:4000]],[x[-1:] for x in dataset[:4000]]
    train_data={X: batch_X, Y_: batch_Y}
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y,1), tf.argmax(Y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
a,c = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=train_data)

test, lebs=[x[:3] for x in dataset[4000:]],[x[-1:] for x in dataset[4000:]]
test_data={X: test, Y_: lebs}                                           
a,c = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=test_data)
prediction=tf.argmax(Y,1)
print ("predictions", prediction.eval({X:test}, session=sess))
```

I got the following results when I ran the above code:

```
predictions [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
```

My expected output should be the class labels:

```
predictions `[0,1,2....]`
```

I will appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code:

**Initialisation**:  You are zero initializing your weight variable.

`W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3,10]))`

Your model will keep propogating same values at each layer for all types of inputs if you zero initialize it. Initialize it with random values. Ex:

`W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((3,10)))`

**Loss function**: I believe you are trying to replicate this familiar looking equation as your loss function:
`y * log(prob) + (1 - y) * log(1 - prob)`. I believe you are having totally 10 classes. For each of the 10 classes, you will have to substitue the above equation and remember, you will use `y` value in above equation as either correct class or wrong class i.e 1 or 0 only for each class. Do not substitute y value as class label from 0 to 9.

To avoid all this calculations, I will suggest you to make use of Tensorflow's in-built functions like `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. It will help you in a long way.

**Sigmoid function**: **This is the prime culprit on why all your outputs are giving value as only 0**. The output range of sigmoid is from 0 to 1. Think of replacing it with ReLU.

**Output units**: If you are doing classification, your number of neurons in final layers should be equal to number of classes. Each class denotes one output class. Replace it with 10 neurons.

**Learning rate**: Keep playing with your learning rate. I believe your learning rate is little high for such a small network.

Hope you understood the problems in your code. Please Google each of the above point I have mentioned for greater details but I have given you more than enough information to start solving the problem.

Comment: many thanks for the detailed explanation, I spent some time on the internet going through the stuff you mentioned, and made the adjustments and its now working perfectly. I got about 93% accuracy and I'm trying different learning rates and neurons. I might even extend to three layers. Thanks again.